# yii create a clean app without assets

Tags: yii

I use `./yiic webapp /path/to/name` create a project, but I don't need some file that created.

Actual:
  `assets  css  images  index.php  index-test.php  protected  themes`

Expected:
  `index.php protected`

Where is template that I should to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to really change this you should extend ( or modify) the class WebAppCommand that is part of the framework. It can be found in

```
Yii
-> Framework 
   ->cli
     -> commands
       ->WebAppCommand.php
```

Instead of modifying the exisiting code i suggest you write a custom class that extends `WebAppCommand` class and just remove the directories in separate method that calls the run method of `WebAppCommand` and adds additional lines to delete the unnecessary directories.
Perhaps something like this...

```
<?php 
 class MyCustomWebAppCommand extends WebAppCommand {
      private $_rootPath; // Need to redefine  and compute this as thevariable is defined as private in the parent class and better not touch core classes;
      public function run($args){
          parent::run($args);
          $path=strtr($args[0],'/\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
          if(strpos($path,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)===false)
          $path='.'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path;
          if(basename($path)=='..')
          $path.=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'.';
          $dir=rtrim(realpath(dirname($path)),'\\/');
          if($dir===false || !is_dir($dir))
              $this->usageError("The directory '$path' is not valid. Please make sure the parent directory exists.");
          if(basename($path)==='.')
              $this->_rootPath=$path=$dir;
          else
              $this->_rootPath=$path=$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.basename($path);
              $this->deleteDir($this->_rootPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."assets");
              $this->deleteDir($this->_rootPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."themes");
              $this->deleteDir($this->_rootPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."images");
              $this->deleteDir($this->_rootPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."css");
              unset($this->_rootPath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."index-test.php");
      }


       public static function deleteDir($dirPath) {
          if (! is_dir($dirPath)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("$dirPath must be a directory");
          }
          if (substr($dirPath, strlen($dirPath) - 1, 1) != '/') {
             $dirPath .= '/';
          }
          $files = glob($dirPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
          foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (is_dir($file)) {
               self::deleteDir($file);
             } else {
               unlink($file);
             }
         }
         rmdir($dirPath);
         }
}
```

Finally call MyCustomWebApp instead of calling WebApp.

P.S. I would generally suggest **not** to extend/modify core classes without knowing what you are doing, it will break lot of things in places you won't anticipate, and upgrades become extremely difficult. Simpler in your case is to delete the files manually.